# Apt-mirror for amd64 did not include focal/main/dep11 and focal/main/cnf/Commands-amd64

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

I try to create a local version apt-mirror of ubuntu 20.04 repositories.
But I do not succeed to upload   focal/main/dep11 and focal/main/cnf/Commands-amd64
and the command

```
apt-get update
...
E: Impossible de récupérer http://mirror/ubuntu/dist/focal/main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar 404 Not Found ..
E: Impossible de récupérer http://mirror/ubuntu/dist/focal/main/cnf/Commands-amd64 404 Not Found ..
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`apt-mirror` is not maintained and has several bugs for missing files for newer releases.  You can either patch the installed version or install a fork with incorporated patches

Browsing the bug reports, you'll see the reported issues

- https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/

One such fork

- https://github.com/Stifler6996/apt-mirror

Comment: I use the fork solution **apt-mirror** script and it works perfectly.  ubuntu/dists/focal/main/cnf and ubuntu/dists/focal/main/dep11 are created now

Comment: _The issue is solved. I do not know are to indicate it in the question_

Comment: Thanks to @Andrew solution