# Trying to set up offline Repo; fails a lot

Tags: apt, ssh, dependencies

I have about 20 Ubuntu 20.04 servers and desktops on an air-gapped network that I would like to update, as well as provide the package repo so I can install additional software.

A hundred "how to" web pages later, I'm still not any closer to it working.

In brief, on a freshly updated 20.04.3 server (on the internet, obviously), I install apt-mirror and edit mirror.list to have only one source -- deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main

Apt-mirror runs fine, but it doesn't download everything required. The hash directories and cnf directories aren't downloaded at all, as well as a few files in dep11 (the icons*@2.tar.gz never seem to get pulled down). So I fire up wget and pull all that data down as well.

I put all this stuff in a directory and chown it to www-data:www-data, and then I am able to browse the directories with a web browser.

On a 20.04.1 desktop VM that I keep, I change the sources.list file to have only this repo available ( deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.0.117/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main ). Apt-get is happy (no errors or ignores). But when I ask it to install something, I end up in dependency hell. For example, trying to install openssh-server, I get:

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt install openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:8.2p1-4) but 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
                  Depends: openssh-sftp-server but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ncurses-term but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ssh-import-id but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@ubuntu:~#
```

openssh-ftp-server won't install because it depends on openssh-client. openssh-client IS installed...but it's version number has ubuntu0.2 tacked on to the end, so it appears to not meet the required dependencies. (ncurses-term and ssh-import-id install fine by themselves).

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Are you mirroring the updates and security repos? I have a 20.04 local mirror working well. apt-mirror in the repos is old and I did have to add cmds for the c-n-f files.

Comment: I used this apt-mirror fork https://askubuntu.com/a/1252842/243321

Comment: No updates or security -- trying to keep this as light weight as possible (by update in the OP I meant going from 20.04.1 to 20.04.3). I will check out the forked version of apt-mirror