# Prepare repo vm for Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, repository

Assume there are 10 VM's, installed w Ubuntu 18 (Bionic Beaver).

As a security regulation, only 1 specific 'repo server' download packages via the internet from an external repo. The remaining VM's are not connected to the internet, and download packages via this repo server. The VM's configure this in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. This works properly.

Now, the issue I'm struggling with is preparing the upgrade of the environment to Ubuntu 20.04. The repo server should have packages available for an upgrade.

How can I configure the repo server to:

1. Download packages for Ubuntu 20.04, without meddling with the Ubuntu 18.04 packages placed on disk
2. Download only the 'latest' and/or required packages for 20.04, instead of downloading 'all' packages
3. Ensure all 'other' required files are present on this vm, so other the clients can easily perform the upgrade
4. Download only files for the sources, as currently configured:

```bash
deb http://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted multiverse
deb http://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted multiverse
deb http://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
```

FYI, [apt-mirror](https://apt-mirror.github.io/) is currently used to clone files from an external repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use `apt-mirror` and transitioned from 18.04 to 20.04.

Long story short, I just added the 20.04 sources to my `mirror.list`. This worked fine as far as downloading the packages. However...

You will run into problems there, because `apt-mirror` is not maintained, and changes in how apt works in 20.04 broke it. (see this Q&A [Apt-mirror for amd64 did not include focal/main/dep11 and focal/main/cnf/Commands-amd64](https://askubuntu.com/q/1252828/243321)) I had to go to `https://github.com/Stifler6996/apt-mirror` and download a forked version. This helped greatly, but still was not a complete fix. I had to add these lines to my `postmirror.sh` to unpack the c-n-f files.

```
unxz -fk [mirror location]/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz
unxz -fk [mirror location]/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz
unxz -fk [mirror location]/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz
unxz -fk [mirror location]/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/universe/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz
#
unxz -fk [mirror location]/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz
unxz -fk [mirror location]/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz
unxz -fk [mirror location]/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz
unxz -fk [mirror location]/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/universe/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz
```

(I may have done a one-time unzip on the basic repo, I can't remember)

After all that, the mirror worked well for 20.04. Once I transitioned all the systems from 18.04, I removed the 18.04 lines from `mirror.list` and `apt-mirror` cleaned up the mirror automatically.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll try it tomorrow. You still have those postmirrror.sh lines?

Comment: @KevinC I just added them to the answer.