# Hash Sum Mismatch Local Mirror

Tags: 20.04, apt-mirror, localrepository

I'm currently running Ubuntu 20.04 and a local mirror server after following [this](https://www.linuxtechi.com/setup-local-apt-repository-server-ubuntu/) process. Also, this machine is a VM running on a 2012R2 Hyper-V cluster.

I'm finding that a server trying to do an update to it runs into a hash sum mismatch error after the nightly `cron` job runs. If I remove all the data in the `archive.ubuntu.com` directory in `/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror`, then rerun the `/usr/bin/apt-mirror` and `cnf.sh` script, then updates work as normal. However, after the `cron` job runs, everything stops working and the hash sum mismatch comes back again.

As far as I can see, the issue lies with the CNF files. I've made sure there is ample space on the server. I've checked the `cnf.sh` file and made sure only the amd64 files are downloading.

Tried running these commands to troubleshoot as well:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need any other information.

Thank you!

Comment: Since you set it up, has it ever worked, or is this an intermittent problem? If it never works, see here for how to unzip the cnf files https://askubuntu.com/a/1426983/243321

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It has worked for my system behind a proxy:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing --fix-broken
```

When there are many pending updates, I've found running this sequence twice has been necessary to get all the packages updated.

Hope this helps.

*Note: My system is a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS console-only, running on an industrial PC in a private and secured network segment. It has access just to a single machine in the corporate network that runs a proxy for this sole machine.*

Answer (score 0):

My solution was remove the archive.ubuntu directory created by cnf.sh script, then run it again. After that, run the "sudo cp -av archive.ubuntu.com  /var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/".

This solves my hash sum mismatch problem.