# alternative for apt-mirror

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

We were using Ubuntu 18.04, and used apt-mirror to download packages from external sources. We were happy w that solution.

However, we recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, and experience a broken apt-mirror application. It currently fails to download certain packages.
We see that the code is written in perl and is not maintained anymore...

Thus, we are looking for an alternative.

We do not want to resort to using rsync, since that will download the complete repo, instead of only the 'latest' packages.  rysnc also doesn't clean up.

**Q:** Are there any good applications out there to download packages from an external source, such as apt-mirror, but which are still working, maintained and have some functionality, e.g. a clean-up function?

Comment: I was in the same boat. You can get it to work for 20.04 by following the procedure in my answer here https://askubuntu.com/q/1426807/243321  It's working fine for 20.04 now. Posting as a comment because it doesn't answer your question about an alternative, but tells you how to fix it.

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see that I'm the same person asking that question. So yeah, I've applied the patch, but still, broken :D

Comment: Oops, sorry, best wishes! If you ask a different question with specifics about what isn't working, I might be able to help.  In any case, I'll follow this question and hope you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've used https://github.com/aptly-dev/aptly
Has been working well for our needs, but takes a bit of reading to get up and running.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1290835)