How to Create ubuntu 24.04 LTS Apt Mirror Server
Please help me to create a local apt mirror server. I wanted only the OS updates hence added only main repository.
Please validate if this is correct
[My Configuration Steps]
vi /etc/apt/mirror.list
#Add the Following Configuration to the mirror.list File

set base_path /var/spool/apt-mirror
set mirror_path $base_path/mirror
set skel_path $base_path/skel
set var_path $base_path/var
set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
set defaultarch amd64
set nthreads 20
set _tilde 0

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security main

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

Run sudo apt-mirror
sudo apt-mirror

Install Apache if it’s not already installed:
sudo apt-get install apache2

Create Apache Config
vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/apt-mirror.conf

Add the following content:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName aus-ntnx-ubuntu.bmc.com
    ServerAdmin ausbmcub24repo@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com
    <Directory /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Enable the new site and restart Apache:
sudo a2ensite apt-mirror.conf
sudo systemctl reload apache2

Configure Client Machines
On client machines, create a new source file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ to point to your local repository server:
Create a new source file:
vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources

deb http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu.bmc.com/ubuntu noble main
deb http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu.bmc.com/ubuntu noble-updates main
deb http://aus-ntnx-ubuntu.bmc.com/ubuntu noble-security main

move the .sources to .list
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.list

sudo apt clean
sudo apt update


Please do not show pictures of text. Always cut and past into the question. That way they can be searched and more easily read.

Looks like wrong URL for "noble-security". Seems like unnecessary repo for "noble" (no updates in it).

When I had an Ubuntu mirror I had to tweak it a lot because the apt-mirror package was really out of date. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1426983/243321 But it got updated in the last year or so, maybe it works better now. It works in Debian without the tweaking.

@DavidDE Got it , I have pasted the entire config command line in my question

For the three Ubuntu systems I still have, I did as @user535733 recommended and use a caching proxy. It works well except I haven't gotten it to work with https repos yet, and that will become more important as those systems transition to esm.

What's the actual problem you're having? Did you test your configuration and face any actual issues?

@muru
I wanted to if this is the right configuration to got OS related packages, just to support the security patches. Am I missing something

Did you miss something when you tried it?

I recommend to use undocumented
set _autoclean 1
set unlink 1

options otherwise:

you need to setup cron job which should run autogenerated clean script
you will got 100% broken mirror while apt-mirror is running

Please note, that apt-mirror have many issues which lead to broken mirrors (even with options I mentioned) and currently unmaintained.
You can use apt-mirror2 with the same config to create reliable mirrors.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

My mirror gets cleaned by the clean directives in mirror.list. No cron job required. Never had "100% broken mirror" whatever that means.

"My mirror gets cleaned by the clean directives in mirror.list. No cron job required".
You are wrong. Here is relevant apt-mirror code: https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/blob/master/apt-mirror#L1085
Without _autoclean directive clean script is written, but it should be executed "by hand".

There are a lot of ways apt-mirror can broke your mirror. One of the changes (https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/commit/27f92ff5247fe8df3656021d53dfcf680012e36f) makes hard-links instead of copy from skel to mirror which "ruins" your dists on every apt-mirror run and until it finished. That's why unlink option is needed - to break hardlinks before overwrite files in the skel folder
